# Usin jquery how to make an element clickable only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in my JS file:-

```
var $html = $('<div class="chat self" style="justify-content: flex-end;">' +
                '<p class="chat-message" style="cursor: pointer;">' +
                       'message' +
                '</p>' +
              '</div>'
            );
 $html.find('p').click(() => cast_vote(url, option_position, vote_count));
```

The click function gets called all the times when the element is clicked.
How do i make the element to be clicked only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)  handler. According to the API, "The `.one()` method is identical to `.on()`, except that the handler for a given element and event type is unbound after its first invocation."

You're using [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) which is shorthand for `.on( "click", handler )`.  Change your code to:

```
$html.find('p').one('click', () => cast_vote(url, option_position, vote_count));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add a class like "disabled" to the element on click, then check if the element has that tag before you run the cast_vote function again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the element after clicking it, and check each time one of the elements is clicked to see if it has this class.

The example below shows you how you can do this.

---

## Demo

```js
// Add click event to wrapping .message_box
$(".message_box").on("click", ".message", function() {

  // Check if the clicked message has the clicked class
  // If it doesnt, run script
  if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {

    // Add clicked class to message
    // This means no further click events will run the code below
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    console.log("Clicked");

  }

});
```

```css
.message {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
  margin: 4px;
}

.clicked {
  border-left-color: blue;
}

.user1 {
  float: left;
}

.user2 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message_box">
  <div class="message user1">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="message user2">
    Hi!
  </div>
  <div class="message user1">
    How are you?
  </div>
  <div class="message user2">
    Good thanks
  </div>
  <div class="message user2">
    and you?
  </div>

</div>
```